# Binding Comboboxes which are in listbox to the viewmodels property(s)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, combobox

Please look at the image below:

[image]

Only three items in the listbox are displayed in the above image but it can be any number of items depending on the user's choice.

Now, as you can see in the image above each item has two comboboxes. Now I want to have `selectedItem` or `SelectedValue` in my viewModel from which I should be able to get the user's selection. Now I don't know how to bind these comboboxes for getting the user's selection.

Suppose I have only one item instead of the list then I would declare a property of type int so that I can easily get the selectedValue but for the list I am very much confused. Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: What does your Xaml look like? What does your model look like. Remember you ViewModel should be a model of your View. So I see your view as being a list of object A.
Now Object A is contains a Unit list (both drop downs share the same list) a UnitSelected and a AlertnateUnitSelected property. Each drop down binds to their respective selected property.

Comment: In the above comment you mentioned that `UnitSelected` and `AlternateUnitSelected` properties should be defined in the viewmodel. I agree with that. But the items in the above list will be added or deleted by the user, so I dont know the number of items in the list. So, how can I decide that I have to define how many properties for UnitSelected like UnitSelected1 for 1st ListItem, UnitSelected2 for 2nd ListItem and so on....?

Comment: You just answered you own question with the word "List". You need to have a List<Unit> SelectedUnits. Then the xaml template for you parent ListBox would include it own child ListBox.

Comment: Yes that would be just fine enough. I will try it and let you know the results. Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start of, lets say the class you are going to be binding the combo box is

```
public class UnitSource :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable Units
    {
        get { return new[] { "Test Unit", "Alternate Unit" }; }
    }

    string _selectedComboItem1;
    public string SelectedComboItem1
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedComboItem1;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedComboItem1 == value)
                return;
            _selectedComboItem1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string _selectedComboItem2;
    public string SelectedComboItem2
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedComboItem2;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedComboItem2 == value)
                return;
            _selectedComboItem2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in your view model you will have  an ObservableCollection of the `UnitSource`  Like below

```
    public ObservableCollection<UnitSource> MuchoUnitSources
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

To get the selected ListBoxItem have this in your ViewModel

```
private UnitSource _selectedUnitSource;
    public UnitSource SelectedUnitSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUnitSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedUnitSource == value)
                return;
            _selectedUnitSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }
```

Lets assume it is initialized like so

```
MuchoUnitSources = new ObservableCollection<UnitSource>(new []{ new UnitSource(),new UnitSource() });
```

The in your view  your listbox should look like  below

```
    <ListBox Name ="TestList1" ItemsSource="{Binding MuchoUnitSources}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnitSource}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <ComboBox   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboItem1}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" />
                    <ComboBox   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboItem2}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Now whenever you select an item from any of the combobox they will update the objectbeing bound to.

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing that you have described above. Now my question is : Suppose I have 5 `ListItems`. Thus I would have 5 `ComboBoxes` for Units and 5 `ComboBoxes` for `AlternateUnits`. Now, I will have 5 `SelectedUnits` and 5 `SelectedAlternateUnits`. But in the viewmodel the datatype of SelectedUnits and SelectedAlternateUnits is string as per your answer. Then how can a string hold more than one `SelectedItems`?

Comment: It doesn't have to be strings, I could have usedan object. The idea here is that each listbox Item is bound to one unitsource and selected combobox items are bound to a property in that unitsource. Selections in one  unitsource updates that unitsource's property. Comboboxes to my knowledge dont allow more than one item selection.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me or might be I am misunderstanding you. One Combobox can have only one item selection but there are multiple comboboxes so, there will be multiple selected Items.

Comment: And the solution I gave you helps with what you said. Every item in the ObservableCollection of UnitSource has a selectedItem for each ComboBox. You have that observable collection so have each selected value (i.e. you can iterate the collection and get the selectedvalues). If you need to aggregate them in some other form then thats extra work you will have to do.

Comment: Now I got it. Thats what your above comment pointed to me. Thanks for the wonderful answer.

Comment: Can you please answer my small question? I want to have `List<SelectedItems> = List<SelectedComboItem1> + List<SelectedComboItem2>` But I don't know how to get `List<SelectedComboItem1>` and `List<SelectedComboItem2>`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48722/discussion-between-vishal-and-tyy)